# Not able to update the user profile properties of any other user

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, active-directory

I am trying to update the user profile properties (CellPhone for example)
using the below code in SharePoint online by power-shell.

## Mysite URL

```
$site = 'site url'
```

## Admin User Principal Name

```
$admin = 'user login'
```

## Get Password as secure String

```
$password = "Password" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force
```

## Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
```

## Authenticate

```
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
```

## Fetch the users in Site Collection

```
$users = $context.Web.SiteUsers
$context.Load($users)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

## Create an Object [People Manager] to retrieve profile information

```
$people = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($context)
 

$userprofile = $people.GetPropertiesFor("useraccount")
$context.Load($userprofile)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
 

$people.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($userprofile.AccountName, "CellPhone", "1234567890")
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

I've created a trial O365 SharePoint site and I'm the admin of the site.

I'm able to update my phone no. using the above code but getting access denied for any other user.

I've tried to update the properties of an external user(Hotmail) that I've added in my site also I tried with a test user account that I created with the same domain of my site. I'm getting access denied for both.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you provide the tenant admin credentials?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I just resolved this by connecting to the admin console ie. mysite-admin.sharepoint.com  earlier i was trying to connect to my root site so getting access denied.

Comment: i could change the phone no. but i want to change the profile picture,  so in the line: $people.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($userprofile.AccountName, "CellPhone", "1234567890") i can use pictureURl instead of cellphone but what value do i provide in the url

Comment: If you have resolved it please post it as an answer and ask a new question for your new issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the issue admin console:

```
$site = ''https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com'
Admin User Principal Name

$admin = 'user login'
Get Password as secure String

$password = "Password" |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -force
Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
Authenticate

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($admin , $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
Fetch the users in Site Collection

$users = $context.Web.SiteUsers
$context.Load($users)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
Create an Object [People Manager] to retrieve profile information

$people = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($context)


$userprofile = $people.GetPropertiesFor("useraccount")
$context.Load($userprofile)
$context.ExecuteQuery()


$people.SetSingleValueProfileProperty($userprofile.AccountName, "CellPhone", "1234567890")
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Use `https://mysite-admin.sharepoint.com` in the site url instead of root site

`https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Testsite`
and you will not get access denied while updating other user's profile, provided you should be the global admin